# Arrow keys not working while editing answers or comments

Tags: bug, status-norepro, editor, keyboard

Using IE9 on Windows 7 when I type a comment or an answer that exceeds the available vertical size of the editing control (so there is a vertical scroll bar) the arrow keys stop working properly: the up arrow moves only one or two lines up and then stops, the right arrow moves up to that same line and then keeps cycling there.

To reproduce it for the comments: create a new comment and paste the following text into it:

First second third fourth. First second third fourth. First second third fourth. First second third fourth. First second third fourth. First second third fourth. First second third fourth. First second third fourth. First second third fourth. First second third fourth. First second third fourth. First second third fourth. First second third fourth. First second third fourth.

The caret is after the last `.` - and the up arrow cannot move to the first line, it stops after a couple of lines (or zero sometimes).

**UPDATE**

It is not a StackOverflow bug - I had the same problem on another Web site - it is something weird related to my system. I'll try to understand what's causing the problem and post it here as an answer.

Comment: I can't reproduce this, at least for the answer textarea.

Comment: @Asad: thanks for checking. I don't have it all the time, I added a sequence to reproduce it - see if that helps.

Comment: I'll status-norepro this in the meantime since you've determined it to be something else, but I haven't closed it so you can still post your findings later. Thanks for the follow-up!

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn: thanks! I did not know about that tag...

Comment: It's a tag that only moderators and employees can use :) (The same goes for all other red tags.)